# selecting the option tag of a select in HTML via jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code that worked well on all browsers except Google chrome, I really do not know why.

### HTML

```
<div class='form-group text-center' >   
    <label><h4>What card is it?</h4>
        <select name='card' id='select_card' class='form-control input-lg' >
            <option value=''>Select a card</option>
            <option value='card A'>card A</option>
            <option value='card B'>card B</option>
            <option value='other_card' id='other_card' >Other card</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$('#other_card').click(function(){
    alert('other card');
});
```

---

Comment: Listen to change event of the select and check the selected value.

Comment: add more information as to what do you mean by `code that worked well on all browsers except Google chrome`

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/k08d15mr/)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't even thought that `option` has a click event. I thinks the correct way would be, to watch the whole select.

```
$("#select_card").change(function() {
    if( $(this).val() == "other_card" )
        alert("other card");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use change of the select instead of click on option. Don't  need to use id in option tag.

```
$('#select_card').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "other_card") {
        alert('other card');
    }
});
```

Comment: That didn't work. The select changes, not the option.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

Html

```
<div class='form-group text-center'>
    <label>
        <h4>What card is it?</h4>
        <select name='card' id='select_card' onchange="selectChange(this)" class='form-control input-lg'>
            <option value=''>Select a card</option>
            <option value='card A'>card A</option>
            <option value='card B'>card B</option>
            <option value='other_card' id='other_card'>Other card</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div
```

Script

```
    function selectChange(e) {
if($(e).val()=="other_card"){
alert("other card")
}
    }
```

Comment: This is not the same behavior as wanted in the question. So it's not an correct answer here.

Comment: i have Updated the code.Or else you can elaborate the Expected behaviour .

Comment: It works, I get it! I failed to realise that all my form fields were not the same and I was busy listening for a click.

Comment: Congrats....Well if it works for you , you can mark it as an answer right??